# INDIRECT function not recognizing the range of cells

Tags: excel

I've been trying to construct an INDIRECT formula. Here's the formula that I've created:

```
{=INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A5)&":H"&ROW(A5))}
```

The problem is that the INDIRECT function doesn't recognize the range of cells (i.e., D5:H5). The goal is to get the list of values, but it only extracts the first entry (i.e., D5). Can anyone tell me if I'm missing an important rule for INDIRECT here? Thank you.

Comment: what version of excel are you using? Works fine for me on Office365 2019

Comment: Excel 2019 Desktop Version. I think that the formula should work also. Hmmm. If i try doing it this way: INDIRECT("D5:H5"), it works fine. If I also use a helper column to concatenate the references ="D"&ROW(A5)&":H"&ROW(A5) and then, reference that concatenation inside the INDIRECT function, it also works fine. But when I combine everything into one formula, it doesn't work.

Comment: `ROW(A5)` should evaluate to 5, I assume the formula you're entering is not in A5 (as this will give a circular reference). What is the desired output? Maybe you should consider using `OFFSET` instead.

Comment: Index may work in this case. Can you some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @TomNavidi, the formula is in column B. I'm actually using the result of the INDIRECT function in a LOOKUP formula. The goal is to search the lookup value from the values returned by the INDIRECT function. I was debugging it, and I found out that the INDIRECT function is not returning the values from the given range of cells. To simplify it, if the formula that I've posted above will work, then I can work it out.

Comment: @Harun24HR, I'm using INDIRECT because I need to incorporate dynamic Sheet reference. For the expected output, I just want the INDIRECT formula to return the values from the text reference. If I hit F9, I just want to see that the values are returned correctly by the INDIRECT function. Currently, If you hit F9, it will only show the value from D5.

Comment: What if you wrap it in a `textjoin`, i.e. `=TEXTJOIN(", ",FALSE, INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A6)&":H"&ROW(A6)))`, maybe this will give you an indication on what is wrong (do not use CSE on this example) (edit: sorry, fixed wrong order in arguments)

Comment: @TomNavidi, thanks for the suggestion. Wrapping the text reference by TEXTJOIN solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create  'an Array formula':
Just write INDIRECT("D"&ROW(A5)&":H"&ROW(A5))
And finish with CTRL SHIFT ENTER

Comment: Yes. As you can see in the formula above, there are curly brackets, which indicate that I'm using the CSE.

Comment: You dont need beed to write the bracket on your own, you just need to write the formula  above and press Ctrl shift  enter

Comment: I'm using CSE (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

Comment: And as i said,  you're not using it right. The brackets shouldn't contain the formula alone, it should contain the '=' sign, which means you're not using it right.

Comment: Again, I'm using CSE. That's not the problem. I know how to use array formulas.